# Django STATIC_URL clarification

Tags: python, django, static, django-staticfiles

I have read other topics on stackoverflow and on the django website, but I am still confused.

These are my configurations:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

When I run `manage.py collectstatic` , my static files will be collected at `myproject/assests/`

I will store a default profile photo (for using with my models) here: `myporject/static/images/default_profile_photo.png`, so when I run collect static, it will be coppied in `myproject/assets/images/default_profile_photo.png`

Everything fine so far.

On my **models.py** I have a field:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = get_upload_file_name,
                              storage = OverwriteStorage(),
                              default = 'path/to/my/default/image.jpg'))
```

My main question is: what path should I set to this default atribute? should I benefit from the STATIC_URL somehow?

Other questions: How can I user here the STATIC_URL from settings.py? and what is the usage of STATIC_URL? where and how can I see the effect between using STATIC_URL='/static/' and STATIC_URL='/wtf/'

Answer (score 0):

```
   os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))), 'static', 'templates'),
```

for each "os.path.dirname( )" I have one more within the following, which corresponds to a parent directory, so in my example I have four of them, it clarifies the root folder as being 4 folders above the current directory.

Comment: with what you said, this is how it looks in my case: return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))), 'assets', 'images', 'generic_profile_photo.png'). I'm still hard-coding the 'assets' word. Moreover, my default image is not loaded. I am getting "UserProfile matching query does not exist" when I try to take the picture fomr the DB: source_file = UserProfile.objects.get(user = request.user).photo

Answer (score 0):

Files that are uploaded always go in a subdirectory of `MEDIA_ROOT` and are referenced from `MEDIA_URL`.

For any `FileField` (like `ImageField`), you simply give the *subdirectory* that will be used to store the files that are uploaded to this model.

If you have `MEDIA_ROOT` as `'/foo/bar/uploads/'`, then in your models you have this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')
```

Then all photos uploaded will be stored in `/foo/bar/uploads/photos/`.

Unlike `collectstatic`, there is no command to manage media files. You have to deal with them on your own.

Now on setting a default value; in addition to a path, you can add the name of a *callable* (a function), that is called whenever an instance of the object is saved. You can exploit this:

```
import os

from django.contrib.staticfiles import finders
from django.config import settings


def get_default_photo_path():
   results = finders.find('/default/image.jpg')
   if results:
       return os.path.join(settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0], results[0])

class Foo(models.Model):

    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos',
                              default=get_default_photo_path, null=True)
```

Now, whenever a new object is created, the default value is the static file path to `/default/image.jpg`. If for some reason this file doesn't exist (for example, you forgot to add it), `None` will be returned. In other to store that, you have to set `null=True`.

Comment: I get an error when trying to do manage.py runserver: The joined path (C:\images\default_profile_photo.png) is located outside of the base path component. I'm doing results = finders.find('/images/default_profile_photo.png') .  And is supose this results will have 2 elements (because it finds the image under /assets/images, ass well the one under /static/images)

Comment: `find` will return the first that it finds, but you have to append the path to the `STATICIFILE_DIRS` directory from where the file was found. I have updated the example, to show how to append the first item in the `STATICFILE_DIRS` tuple to return a complete path.

Comment: still not working. has the path to be the abosulte path? cause if so, I did default = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT,'images','generic_profile_photo.png')